# Chicken nuggets come in boxes of $389$ and $691$. What is the largest number of nuggests one cannot order?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Chicken nuggets come in boxes of $389$ and $691$. What is the largest number of nuggets one cannot order?

Comment: See [the Chicken McNugget Theorem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem).

Comment: I've never seen more that $20$ nuggets a box in my life

Comment: This question is quite interesting. However the execution was quite horrible...(-0)